# API Manager - export users and keys

Tags: wso2

We're looking to upgrade to API Manager 1.6 from 1.4. We have a very minimal setup with only about 9 users and 2 API's published. In this upgrade, we also are trying to move away from mysql cluster over to postgres. I've gone down the rabbit hole of attempting to convert the data into the postgres db with no luck. Is there anyway to easily export the users/keys/api's without having to migrate the entire DB? It would be nice if I could just put up a fresh install of the latest version and import that info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no possible way to import/export APIs from a running AM instance.But importing users to a new instance via .csv/.xsl sheet is possible currently as mentioned in [1].Such that since you already have APIM data,better option is to try moving APIM mysql data to postgre sql by an existing db tool first and then try migrate those data from 1.4.0 to 1.6.0 with postgre.

Once the existing data moved to postgre ,to migrate from AM 1.4.0 to 1.6.0,try below two steps.
First try migrate from AM 1.4.0 ->1.5.0
--For this use the migration script {AM_Home}/dbscripts/migration-1.4.0_to_1.5.0 and its included readme file.

Then try migrate from AM 1.5.0 ->1.6.0
-- For this use the migration script which can be found from https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.6.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.5.0_to_1.6.0/

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/Configuring+Users#ConfiguringUsers-Importingusers

Answer (score 0):

Did u try the migration scripts that are available with the API Manager distribution. It can be found in `<APIM_Home>/dbscripts`